# Best architecure approach to develop iOS app

Tags: design, ios, mobile, xcode, swift-language

I'm trying to create a calendar app similar to this design: [Calendar Design](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/4605/screenshots/1878977/attachments/318416/FullPixels.jpg)

I'm currently using this calendar framework: [CVCalendar](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar) and it's working great, but my question is, what do you think is the best approach to take for displaying the events beneath the calendar?

I see 2 options to take:

Option 1:
I use a UITableView and place the calendar view as the only TableViewCell in it's own section, and the events would be the rows underneath it in a seperate section.

The problem with that, is every time the user selects a new day, I need to load the events pertaining to that day which would require me to reload the whole TableView, including the calendar view which doesn't need to be reloaded.

Option 2:
I create custom views for the events, and add them as subviews in the scroll view along with the calendar view. That way, when the user clicks on a new day, I would just delete the event subviews and recreate them based off of the new data.

Comment: What about the new UIStackView ?

Answer (score 1):

How about option 3. Put the CVCalendarView on the VC's view, and a UITableView under the CVCalendarView. When the user taps a day, reload the table view with the new data. Since the calendar view is not in the table view, it will not need to be reloaded. When the user scrolls through the events of the day, the calendar will stay put.

That's how I would do it.

Option 4. If you really want the calendar to scroll off screen, then put the calendar view in the header view of the table view. Here too the table view can be reloaded without having to reload the calendar view.